# Pass Query to Wordpress URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I used to have this structure of URL when user apply for offer on website:

```
/apply/?apply=8282
```

What I'm trying to do now, is to make it look like

```
/apply/8282
```

I did some research and come up with this 2 simple functions:

```
function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "apply";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );

function custom_rewrite_basic()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^apply/([0-9]+)/?', 'apply?apply=$1', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

However i can't get my ID, :

```
echo "GET APPLY = ".$_GET['apply']."<br />";
```

How to get `8282` id number?

Answer (score 0):

You could basicly access the id like this:

```
$id = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

It will return 8282. Its probably not that clean but its simple and I am using it aswell in a special case.